# How to run a bunch of models in R using a Function

Tags: r, lapply, sapply, mapply, survival

```
library(survival)
justices <- read.csv("http://data.princeton.edu/pop509/justices2.csv")
PREDS = c("age", "year")
m = coxph(Surv(tenure, event == 1) ~ age + year, data = justices)
summary(m)

exp(coef(m)[1])
exp(confint(m,level=(1-0.05/1))[1,])


DVMOD <- function(PREDS, data){
  t <- coxph(paste0("Surv(tenure, event == 1) ~ "), PREDS + number + name, data = data)
  return((c(PREDS, coef(t)[1], confint(t)[1,])))
}

all_models <- lapply(PREDS,DVMOD, PREDS = PREDS, data=justices)
```

I wish to run separate coxph model for each variable in PREDS and then store the name of that variable with its hazard ratio and confidence bands.

Comment: Where is PREDS defined outside the DVMOD function as a list of variables?

Comment: @Len Greski I updated Sorry!

Comment: Have you looked into tidymodels? I understand that is the tidy approach to running a bunch of models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cast the formula string with `as.formula()` you can change independent variables in the `DVMOD()` function as follows:

```
DVMOD <- function(PREDS, data){
     theFormula <- paste("Surv(tenure, event == 1) ~ ",PREDS," + number + name")
     t <- coxph(as.formula(theFormula), data = data)
     return((c(PREDS, coef(t)[1], confint(t)[1,])))
}
DVMOD("age",justices)
all_models <- lapply(c("age"),function(x,y){
     DVMOD(x,y)
},justices)
```

Since the model for `year` does not converge (i.e. it fails when calling `DVMOD()` directly with `year` as the value of `PREDS`), the `lapply()` with 2 variables fails, but it works with `age`.

...and the output:

```
> all_models
[[1]]
                                    age               2.5 %              97.5 % 
              "age"  "24.4400841925434" "-20.8849057264629"  "69.7650741115497" 

>
```